# hide div content using css not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hide div content and place a icon instead text using CSS after but I am not able to hide the text, following are my code:

```css
.masthead > div > .mch-search > span {
  text-indent: -1000em;
}
.masthead > div > .mch-search > span:after {
  content: "Icon";
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mch-logo"> logo</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>nav</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="mch-search"> <span>Search</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-index` only applies to *blocks* and span is, by default `inline`. You need to change the way the `span` displays.

You then need to modify the `::after` element to get it to appear again.

```css
.masthead > div > .mch-search > span {
  text-indent: -1000em;
  display: block;
}
.masthead > div > .mch-search > span:after {
  content: "Icon";
  display: block;
  text-indent: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mch-logo"> logo</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>nav</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="mch-search"> <span>Search</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That said, if you want to display an icon in an accessible way, then HTML has a built in method that doesn't depend on any CSS hacks.

```
<img src="icon.png" alt="Search">
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually I am trying to use the fontawesome icon instead of text thats why not using image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adjust font sizes, like this...

```css
.masthead > div > .mch-search > span {
 font-size: 0;
}
.masthead > div > .mch-search > span:after {
  content: "Icon";
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mch-logo"> logo</div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>nav</li>
        <li>nav</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="mch-search"> <span>Search</span> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```